# How to show JSDoc based prop tooltips in VSCode for React functional component prop?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I have a React functional component:

```
interface ISpecialButton {
  text: string;
}

const SpecialButton: FC<ISpecialButton > = ({
  /* Prop description */
  text 
} = {
  //code
});
```

And would like a developer who uses it in a JSX template to see "Prop description" when he hovers over text prop when adding the `SpecialButton` to a template. I have tried various ways to do it with JSDoc, but none of these work. What is the correct way to use JSDoc for a React functional component so that VSCode shows tooltips?

Comment: @Nate Levin I have tried the exact same thing like in the article and it does not seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface is the one that should be documented so every other place it's going to show the docs when hovering over it. Something like this:

```js
interface ISpecialButton {
  /**
   * Prop description
   */
  text: string;
}

const SpecialButton: React.FC<ISpecialButton> = ({
  text
}) => {
  return <>{ text }</>;
};


const Template: React.FC = () => {
  return <>
    <SpecialButton text='' />
  </>
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Screenshot]